# Why does Safari seem to be accepting an HTTPS connection every other browser rejects?

Tags: tls, web-browser

This question is inspired by a bug/issue in recent Linksys router firmware. Essentially, something has changed recently that's preventing HTTPS access to the web admin on current generation Linksys routers (E4200 and E3000 specifically, although others might be affected as well). This problem shows up in IE, Firefox, Chrome, and Opera, but interestingly not in Safari.

Does Safari handle HTTPS connections in some way that's different from every other browser? Is it accepting SSL certificates that other browsers deem invalid for some reason? I tried doing some research on whether Safari is known to be more lenient when validating SSL certificates but I came up empty. Anyone have any ideas/experience with how Safari handles HTTPS?

Edit: Clarification on "preventing HTTPS access". The error page that gets displayed varies somewhat by browser, but most of them indicate that the connection was reset while the page was loading. IE provides the least informative message simply stating that "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage". My next step I suppose will be installing Ethereal to see if I can get a better idea of what's actually happening.

Comment: Did you check if Safari's settings don't automatically accept untrusted ssl certificates?

Comment: Can you check in another browser (e.g., chrome) why the HTTPS connection is being rejected?

Comment: @tftd Near as I can tell there's nothing like that in the config. It warns me that the certificate is self signed and can't be verified like all the other browsers, and after I add an exception it works.

Comment: @dr jimbob
All the browsers except Safari display an error page claiming the connection was reset during communication. I suspect something in the SSL negotiation is failing.

Comment: That's also the error if you try ssl on http, or http on ssl port.

Comment: Wireshark reports that Firefox is sending a TLSv1 "Bad Certificate" Alert after the initial certificate is sent, and then terminates the connection. For Safari I see a similar "Bad Certificate" Alert, followed by a series of "Change Cipher Spec" messages culminating in a successful connection.

Comment: @Orclev Since you claim this is a firmware bug, could you post a link to somewhere that this bug is being tracked if such place exists?  I don't run Safari, but I think I may be having a similar issue with one of my routers.  I do see "Bad Certificate" alerts in Firefox and IE, and make the selections that generally should allow me to pass through but I still can't get in.

Comment: @Orclev I've verified on my system that the issue does occur in IE, Firefox, and Chrome for my E3000, but not my WRT400N.  Installed Safari, and I could get to the page fine.  The firmware version for my E3000 is 1.0.04.  Could you add this, and the firmware version on your router, into the question?  Also, version numbers for your web browsers would be good.  Mine are:  Firefox - 10.0.02, IE - 9.0.8112.16421, Chrome - 17.0.963.56m, Safari - 5.1.2.

Comment: Verified that my E3000 is running the latest available firmware.  Latest available for your E4200 is 1.0.03 for hardware version 1, and 2.0.36 for hardware version 2.

Comment: @Iszi This isn't so much about the router as it is about the way Safari handles SSL certificates that other browsers seem to think are invalid in some fashion. I didn't feel a IT security forum was the proper place to deal with issues with a bug in router firmware, but accepting invalid SSL certificates certainly is.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a problem with the certificate handling.  Or, at least, it shouldn't be in theory.  Once the user has explicitly told the browser to accept the certificate, the rest of the session should be handled as if there was no problem with it.  Either way, it seems to me like this would be a problem that needs to be handled by either the routers' vendor (most likely) or the browsers' designers.  It should be noted, I'm sure, that these browsers have no such problem on other sites (i.e.: My WRT400N) which have similar certificate issues.

Comment: FTR:  A workaround for this, if you really want to manage the router with other browsers and are willing to accept the risk, is to just enable and use plain HTTP.  Worked for me on my E3000.  Still not sure why Safari is the only one that will work over HTTPS.

Comment: With your sniffer, can you please check two things, both with Safari and with other browsers: (a) What SSL/TLS version is it? (b) what cipher suite is being used? I think this may the root of the issue, Safari will accept some that others do not.

Comment: Have you tried this on another machine running safari to eliminate the possibility of it being a configuration issue?

Answer (score 1):

With Safari, if it cannot validate the certificate, for example because it is self-signed or is signed by an untrusted CA or, quite often, because the server is not sending the intermediate certificate, you can click the "Continue" button on the error dialog and it will automatically store an exception to trust this certificate for this site for the rest of the session (until you quit the browser).  You also have the option of showing the certificate and explicitly saving it as trusted so it will always be trusted in the future.

There is also a preference option to some kinds of certificate errors in general.  In the Security pane of the Preferences window, you can uncheck "Warn when visiting a fraudulent website."  I believe that just fixes host-certificate name mismatches, not invalid certificates in general, but I'm not sure.